# Android Dom4j with threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dom4j

i really need your help. 
I'm trying to create an application on android. 
I try to take some datas from a website that I put in a table. here is my code :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_real_market);
    cell1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rateEur);
    Log.i("test","ici avant le thread");
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HTMLExtractor rates = new HTMLExtractor();
            realMarket = rates.getRates();
            realMarketUpdate = rates.getUpdate();

        }
    } ).start();

    Log.i("test","ici apres le thread");

    this.fillTable();
}
```

to fill my table i use :

```
   public void fillTable(){

    Log.v("test", this.realMarket.get("EUR"));
    System.out.println(this.realMarket.toString());
    cell1.setText(this.realMarket.get("EUR"));

}
```

And this is my HTMLExtrctor where i take the datas that i put in an hash map :

```
   public class HTMLExtractor {
private HashMap<String, String> officialMarket;
private String updateDate;

public HTMLExtractor() {
    this.officialMarket = new HashMap<String, String>();
    this.updateDate = "";
    this.getPage();
}

public void getPage() {
    Document document;
    Element classElement;
    List<Node> nodes;
    try {
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        document = reader.read("i put my URL here ");

        classElement = document.getRootElement();
        nodes = document.selectNodes("/query/results/rate");
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            this.officialMarket.put(
                    node.selectSingleNode("Name").getText().substring(5), node
                            .selectSingleNode("Rate").getText());
            this.updateDate = node.selectSingleNode("Date").getText();
        }

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public HashMap<String,String> getRates() {

    return this.officialMarket;
}

public String getUpdate(){

    return this.updateDate;
}
```

}

I saw on other pages that I can only access to the internet with dom4j using another thread but it looks like I can't put the data from the thread to the variables realMarket and realMarketUpdate here is the error message :

```
   01-28 21:19:50.158  20730-20730/castiel.changes E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: castiel.changes, PID: 20730
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{castiel.changes/castiel.changes.RealMarket}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5308)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:118)
        at castiel.changes.RealMarket.fillTable(RealMarket.java:66)
        at castiel.changes.RealMarket.onCreate(RealMarket.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6072)
```

Comment: You have a NullPointerException within fillTable, where you call Log.V It looks like your realMarket isn't getting properly updated.  I don't see the code here for the `realMarket = rates.getRates();`
where is the `getRates()` method ?

Comment: Look at the HTMLExtractor class (the 3rd one) 
Actually it's working when i run normal Java program but not on android.

Comment: What I exactly want is  : 
The thread runs and then the datas i need will be in the two variables realMarket and realMarketUpdate and then i will use these variables outside of the thread

Answer (score 1):

Good morning everybody i finally found a way after hours of focusing haha 
if anybody is interested, i used AsyncTask to do it here is the code :

```
   private class Download extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    HTMLExtractor rates ;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        rates = new HTMLExtractor();
        rates.getPage();
        return null ;
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        cell1.setText(rates.getRates().get("EUR"));
        cell2.setText(rates.getRates().get("USD"));
        cell3.setText(rates.getRates().get("GBP"));
        cell4.setText(rates.getRates().get("CAD"));
        cell5.setText(rates.getRates().get("AED"));
        cell6.setText(rates.getRates().get("SAR"));
        cell7.setText(rates.getRates().get("TND"));
        cell8.setText(rates.getRates().get("CNY"));
    }
}
```

then i start it in the OnCreate :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_real_market);
    cell1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rateEur);
    cell2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rateUS);
    cell3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rateUK);
    cell4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rateCAD);
    cell5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rateUAE);
    cell6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rateSAD);
    cell7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rateTun);
    cell8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rateCN);
    Log.i("test","ici avant le thread");
    new Download().execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition. You are starting the`Runnable` (which runs asynchronously) to populate the values `realMarket` and `realMarketUpdate`, but then immediately after on the main thread (without ensuring that the `Runnable` has completed and thus filled the values) call `fillTable()` which attempts to do a `get()` on `realMarket`; thus throwing the `NullPointerException`. Move the call to `fillTable()` to be inside the `Runnable` like so:

```
new Thread( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        HTMLExtractor rates = new HTMLExtractor();
        realMarket = rates.getRates();
        realMarketUpdate = rates.getUpdate();
        fillTable();
    }
} ).start();
```